# How to correctly append rows from a df to another based on timestamps on Python? Pandas related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, debugging, unix-timestamp

I currently have 253 csv files with the following filenames:

```
1. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-01.csv
2. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-02.csv
3. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-03.csv
4. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-06.csv
5. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-09.csv
6. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-11.csv
7. ALICEUSDT-1h-2021-06-12.csv
.
.
.
253. ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-13.csv
```

located at this path: `C:\Users\StoreX\AliceUSDT-Mark_Prices_Klines_1h_Timeframe`

Each of those files contains the hourly price action data for a particular asset, having in total 24 rows (**without column names nor indexes**)

Any of those dataframes look like this:

```
    1623369600000   5.53548967  5.8         5.4473946   5.4719309   0   1623373199999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623373200000   5.47278238  5.53195431  5.37178569  5.41425374  0   1623376799999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623376800000   5.41425372  5.439       5.30612058  5.43896918  0   1623380399999   0   3597    0   0   0
    1623380400000   5.439       5.573       5.439       5.51534579  0   1623383999999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623384000000   5.51534611  5.75008683  5.46536508  5.699       0   1623387599999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623387600000   5.699       5.7319193   5.59313511  5.63882188  0   1623391199999   0   3582    0   0   0
    1623391200000   5.63892904  5.65847764  5.50099143  5.52530541  0   1623394799999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623394800000   5.52201075  5.69104913  5.49124857  5.658       0   1623398399999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623398400000   5.6554082   6.336       5.56700781  6.2605508   0   1623401999999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623402000000   6.26056029  6.57769402  6.26056029  6.392       0   1623405599999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623405600000   6.3935684   6.68259312  6.30951189  6.582       0   1623409199999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623409200000   6.58        6.633       6.41970848  6.55150417  0   1623412799999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623412800000   6.55051699  6.56212633  6.34272711  6.44329682  0   1623416399999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623416400000   6.43806578  6.63709121  6.40735932  6.49129756  0   1623419999999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623420000000   6.49097939  6.498       6.19692729  6.25924944  0   1623423599999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623423600000   6.25924944  6.2822904   6.05089683  6.13788357  0   1623427199999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623427200000   6.13764793  6.228       6.005       6.015432    0   1623430799999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623430800000   6.015       6.198       5.97772068  6.19544081  0   1623434399999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623434400000   6.198       6.349       6.13209062  6.2308081   0   1623437999999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623438000000   6.23083904  6.42623752  6.201       6.27776139  0   1623441599999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623441600000   6.27776137  6.31281154  6.02227423  6.036       0   1623445199999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623445200000   6.033       6.185       5.90345962  6.119       0   1623448799999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623448800000   6.119       6.298       6.047       6.20634564  0   1623452399999   0   3600    0   0   0
    1623452400000   6.20606916  6.20606916  5.9779765   6.05824449  0   1623455999999   0   3600    0   0   0
```

> The [Unix Timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) is used to set the exact date at which the
> price was opened (2nd column), and also to set the exact date at which
> it was closed (5th column), the columns with 0 and ≈3600 values do not
> matter.
>
> The 2nd column corresponds to the Open price
>
> The 3rd column corresponds to the High price
>
> The 4th column corresponds to the Low price
>
> The 5th column corresponds to the Close price

I wanted to export a big df with all of the rows from these files, and to do so, I wrote the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def check_path(infile):
    return os.path.exists(infile)   

first_entry = input('Tell me the path where your csv files are located at: ')

while True:
    
    if check_path(first_entry) == False:
        print('\n')
        print('This PATH is invalid!')
        first_entry = input('Tell me the RIGHT PATH in which your csv files are located: ')
        
    elif check_path(first_entry) == True:
        print('\n')
        final_output = first_entry
        break

big_df = pd.DataFrame() 
for name in os.listdir(first_entry):
    if name.endswith(".csv"):
        print(name)
        current_df_path = first_entry+"\\"+name
        df = pd.read_csv(current_df_path, header=None)
        big_df.append(df)
        print(big_df)
print("")        
print("the final df is the following")
print("")
print(big_df)
```

However, it didn't work at all after run, the output was the following:

> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-12.csv Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: []
> ALICEUSDT-1h-2022-02-13.csv Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: []
>
> the final df is the following
>
> Empty DataFrame Columns: [] Index: []

So, I would like to know what did I do wrong? Why isn't the `big_df` actually full of information?

And finally, how could the code above improved to do what's demanded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append returns the dataframe so you would need to write:

```
big_df = big_df.append(df)
```

you could add ignore_index=True to reset the index

Also the default separator for read_csv is a comma so indicate the one used in your file like  sep='\s+' if spaces, '\t' if tab, ...

You may want to start with just loading one file in a dataframe to verify that the filepath is correct and everything work like expected.

Comment: Indeed, as you mentioned, the problem was that I forgot to assign the new `big_df` to the old one in each iteration with `big_df = big_df.append(df, ignore_index=True)`. Do you also happen to know how could I delete all the rows before a particular row in the final `big_df`?

Comment: For instance, the following dates are missing: `[datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 8, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 10, 0, 0)]`, this means that I could not consider rows previous to `datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 11, 0, 0)]` because there are gaps, so how could I delete all the rows previous to **June 11, 2021 12:00:00 AM** ( i.e. `1623369600000` )?

Comment: big_df = big_df[big_df.iloc[:, 0]>=1623369600000]  ?